# Replace Gmail attachments with Dropbox/Google Drive download link

Tags: gmail, google-drive, dropbox, github, attachment

Is there any service, extension or webapp that scans all my incoming and existing email and uploads all attachments within the emails to Dropbox or Google Drive?

This would allow for smaller inboxes and attachments would not pollute multiple email accounts. Also, it would make further processing of the email easier (e.g.: create a GitHub issue from emails).

[image: Example]

Any hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kloudless](https://kloudless.com/) for Chrome provides such a service. Except they currently don't offer support for past emails. According to their [FAQ](https://kloudless.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/89465-does-automation-work-for-past-emails-):

> Automation does not work for past emails at this time. We do think
>   this is a great feature, and we plan on supporting it soon.
>
> If you are interested in using automation on your entire account,
>   please contact us at support@kloudless.com.

You can, however, do this manually. After installing the chrome extension and signing in, you will see a link to Copy/Move the attachment, next to the link to Download it.

Answer (score 0):

So the attachment would be removed from all existing emails and be sent to a Dropbox account (and the email would be edited to provide a link to it)? I don't think that exists, but I wish there was.

I know **it's possible** to remove attachments from an email using Thunderbird (i.e. manually). And then it's possible to drop these files in Dropbox. So technically it's all possible, but perhaps there's no existing service for that.

If you know anything about coding -I'm guessing you do since you mention Github- here's a Python answer that might help you built such a service: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626403/python-email-lib-how-to-remove-attachment-from-existing-message

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with this. You want a solution which will actually *remove attachments* from your email inbox and add them to Dropbox instead.
Making a solution which will give you an option to download the attachments to your dropbox account is doable, but I don't see how you can go about remove attachments without actually deleting the email from your inbox.

If you are talking about a third party email client like Thunderbird, then this is easily possible.